# Unable to create directories and subdirectories

Tags: python, file, directory

So, I'm trying to make folders and subfolders based on date variables. I am getting this error. Can someone assist? The code and the error message is as shown below.

```
for date in date_list:
    year = date.year
    month = date.month
    day = date.day
    newpath = f'C:\Users\divya\OneDrive\Desktop\8th Sem\ISB assignment\{year}'
    if not os.path.exists(newpath):
        os.makedirs(newpath)
    newpath1 = f'C:\Users\divya\OneDrive\Desktop\8th Sem\ISB assignment\{year}\{month}'
    if not os.path.exists(newpath1):
        os.makedirs(newpath1)
    newpath2 = f'C:\Users\divya\OneDrive\Desktop\8th Sem\ISB assignment\{year}\{month}\{day}'
    if not os.path.exists(newpath2):
        os.makedirs(newpath2)
    get_batsmen(date).to_csv(newpath2+'/batsmen.csv')
    get_bowler(date).to_csv(newpath2+'/bowler.csv')
    get_allrounder(date).to_csv(newpath2+'/allrounder.csv')
```

And the error message is as follows:

```
File "c:\Users\divya\OneDrive\Desktop\8th Sem\ISB assignment\main.py", line 67
    newpath = f'C:\Users\divya\OneDrive\Desktop\8th Sem\ISB assignment\{year}'
             ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: \ is an escape character. Add `r`: `newpath = rf'C:\Users\divya\OneDrive\Desktop\8th Sem\ISB assignment\{year}'`

Comment: `\U` is interpreted as prefix of a hexadecimal number denoting a Unicode character. Mark strings as raw to avoid that: `newpath = fr'C:\Users...`

Answer (score 2):

The backlash is the [escape character](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp) in Python, so when python sees `\U` it interprets it as the start of a unicode character (which takes the form `\UXXXXXXXX`, hence the error text), and not a regular "backlash U".

You can get a 'real' backslash by putting another backslash before it, so the full string becomes something like `"C:\\Users\\username\\path\\to\\directory"`.